# Do goldfishes have a two or three seconds memory?

Tags: zoology

It is often claimed that goldfishes have a very short memory, usually of two or three seconds. Like most claims in the real world, I have yet to see a source provided for it.

So, do goldfishes have a short memory?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From [Fortean Times](http://www.forteantimes.com/strangedays/mythbusters/706/forgetful_fish.html):

> **Ichthyologists have known for a long time that this isn't true, and in
> 2003 Dr Phil Gee, of the School of Psychology at the University of
> Plymouth, [published research](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1334363/) which blew it out of the water**. Goldfish
> have a memory span of at least three months, and can distinguish
> between different shapes, colours and sounds.
>
> In the Plymouth experiments, goldfish were trained to press a lever to
> gain a food reward; when the lever was fixed to work only for an hour
> a day, the fish soon learned to activate it at the correct time.

---

The **MythBusters** have tested this also ([watch the video](http://dsc.discovery.com/videos/mythbusters-goldfish-memory-minimyth.html)):

> **Jamie trained his goldfish to recognize color patterns and complete an
> obstacle course** under water.
>
> They **remembered what Jamie had taught
> them over a month later** and easily completed the same course without
> Jamie’s prompting.
>
> (from [MythBusters Results](http://mythbustersresults.com/episode11))

---

From [ABC News](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2008-02-19/goldfish-three-second-memory-myth-busted/1046710) (2008):

> ... **a 15-year-old schoolboy from Adelaide has just debunked the theory**.
>
> Rory Stokes (a student at the Australian Science and Mathematics School) conducted a school experiment to prove his theory, using a small
> tank of goldfish.
>
> "*I decided to get a bit of red Lego and just feed them next to that.
> Every day I'd put it in and sprinkle food around it*," he said.
>
> "*At first they were a bit scared of it, a bit wary, but by the end of
> the three weeks, they were actually almost coming before I put the
> food in*."
>
> After leaving the fish alone for a week, Rory placed the red Lego
> block in the tank again.
>
> "*They remembered perfectly well*," he said.