# Did Einstein say the "if you judge a fish" quote that many are attributing to him?

Tags: quotes, albert-einstein

The quote:

> “Everybody is a genius. But if you judge a fish by its ability to
>   climb a tree, it will live its whole life believing that it is
>   stupid.”

I'm just not confident that this is something Einstein would say.  I Googled it and was unable to find the quote from a source that I feel is reliable.  I was hoping someone could confirm or deny this attribution. Wikiquotes does not list it.

Related question: [Can any fish climb trees?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5352/can-any-fish-climb-trees)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This one is disputed, as [wikiquote](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein) states.

Searching through [books](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22But%20if%20you%20judge%20a%20fish%20by%20its%20ability%20to%20climb%20a%20tree%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=%22if%20you%20judge%20a%20fish%20by%20its%20ability%20to%20climb%20a%20tree%22&pbx=1&oq=%22if%20you%20judge%20a%20fish%20by%20its%20ability%20to%20climb%20a%20tree%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=14215l14366l0l14526l2l2l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=711d2dd8fab9cdf8&biw=1315&bih=786) you will find only four instances and it sounds possible that these might have been triggered by the first one.

The search for the specific phrase "if you judge a fish by its ability to climb a tree" did not found any suggestion of other sources in the whole corpus of google books.

If you check other, verified quotes you find more [occurrences](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22The%20true%20value%20of%20a%20human%20being%20is%20determined%20primarily%20by%20the%20measure%20and%20the%20sense%20in%20which%20he%20has%20attained%20to%20liberation%20from%20the%20self.%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1): "The true value of a human being is determined primarily by the measure and the sense in which he has attained to liberation from the self." appears in 39 titles.

Comment: What are, in contrast, verified sources? Verified by whom and how? How many quotes between 4 and 39 are the threshold? Why is that?

Comment: According to [this quoteinvestigator article](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2013/04/06/fish-climb/), there is no evidence Einstein said this.

Comment: @Unreason, Where did it say in Wikiquote that it's disputed? It's in the part ["A collection of Einstein's essays which cover a period of 1934 to 1950"](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein)

Comment: @Danny, http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/18140/4098

Comment: Wikiquotes now places this in the "misattributed" section.

Answer (score 2):

**No, he never said this.**

It's unclear where this aphorism originated, but there's no evidence it was Einstein. It does not appear in the comprehensive collection of quotations “The Ultimate Quotable Einstein” from Princeton University Press and [it's quite unlike anything he's known to have said](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2013/04/06/fish-climb/).

Throughout his career, Einstein did not concern himself with trying to make members of the general populace feel "special", but instead [focussed on increasing our understanding of the universe](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/physics/1921/einstein/biographical/).

Aside from that, there is no logic to this aphorism. It attempts to argue that everyone is a "genius" in some capacity, but that is not the case by any widely accepted definition of the word...

By the standard definition, a genius is someone who possesses [an "exceptional human trait"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/genius), especially in the arts or sciences. Arguing that everyone is "exceptional" (or "special") is something you're more likely to find on [Sesame Street](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrPm7BasRBo).

A few more things Einstein never said:

> “Insanity is doing the same thing over and over and expecting different results.” - Original author unknown [Source](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2017/03/23/same/)

> "Compound interest is the eighth wonder of the world. He who understands it, earns it; he who doesn't, pays it." - Originally from an advert [Source](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2019/09/09/interest/)

> "Only two things are infinite: the universe and human stupidity, and I'm not sure about the former." - Probably not, but there is some evidence [Source](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2010/05/04/universe-einstein/)

[More things Einstein didn't say](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein#Misattributed).